# Laravel Cart session returns Object instead of Array, how can I convert the object to an array?

Tags: php, laravel, cart

I am having trouble the last couple of days figuring this out, i tried googling and every answer I come across doesn't fix my problem

I am storing array of items in the cart but when retrieving the array, it's an object.

I want to be able to convert the object to an array.

Here is my code for storing the array in the cart session

```
$cart[$id] = [
        "product_id" => $id,
        "name" => $product->product_name,
        "quantity" => $quantity,
        "total" => $total,
    ];

    $request->session()->put('cart', $cart);
```

but after I get the data from the cart it becomes an object

```
$cart = $request->session('cart');
```

I want to either convert this object back to array or retrieve the cart session data as array in the first place

Comment: Are you sure `$request->session('cart');` is a valid thing to do? The docs mention either `$request->session()->get('cart');` or `session('cart')` but not this syntax

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may solve your problem;

```
$request->session()->get('cart')
```